# Why can't the same node be inserted at two different places in a document?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to insert a button node in a document but for some reasons, it's not getting inserted at both places.

the code is below:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.Tabelle-Titel-nur-oben');
var buttonElement = document.createElement("Button");
var t0 = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
buttonElement.appendChild(t0);
for(var i = 0; i< elements.length; i++)
{

      document.body.insertBefore(buttonElement, elements[i]);
}
```

In my code, there are two elements which get matched for `querySelectorAll`. But my button is only get inserted at the second element. If I use two different button instances it works. I would like to know why a button instance does not get inserted in two places?

Comment: Because the same button instance can only exist once, if you want two buttons, you have to create two buttons.

Comment: Basically, it is restriction by the DOM model: DOM is a _tree_ model, which implies that each node might have as many child nodes as required, but can have only _one_ parent. And if you added your node in two different places, that node would have two parents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `buttonElement` is a reference to the same object, you need to clone it before adding it:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.Tabelle-Titel-nur-oben');
var buttonElement = document.createElement("Button");
var t0 = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
buttonElement.appendChild(t0);
for(var i = 0; i< elements.length; i++)
{
    var btnClone = buttonElement.clone(true);
    document.body.insertBefore(btnClone, elements[i]);
}
```

Or create the button within the loop as @Roberrrt just pointed out as I was about to hit submit.

Comment: I'm actually wondering what would be better (in terms of speed). Cloning or recreating the element.

Comment: @Roberrrt I was literally just asking myself the same thing. I would imagine just creating it may be faster since clone has to loop over the DOM objects properties while it creates a new object. I'm gonna tinker with it and report back

Comment: Unless you're creating many thousands of buttons, the performance difference won't matter. If you are creating many thousands of buttons, then performance is not your main problem :)

Comment: @Pointy 0.003 of a ms is still 0.003 of a ms, time is money!
Also, this is some good feedback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026433/append-clone-or-create-dom-on-the-fly-what-is-better

Comment: @Brian Why referencing to the same object moves to the last node in the nodelist? Please explain it to me.

Comment: @Pointy completely agree but I feel like that's useful information to at least be aware of

Comment: @forethought it doesnt delete it, it just changes where it's reference is called from if that makes sense. For instance, `var testObj = { one: 1 }; var referencesTestObj = testObj; referencesTestObj.one = 2; console.log(testObj);` will output 2

Comment: @Roberrrt it looks like cloning it may be a bit faster since we're not downloading any assets (if I understand that correctly, the accepted answer is a bit confusing) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026433/append-clone-or-create-dom-on-the-fly-what-is-better?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Hmm, you win this time, but there's a catch! You're creating the original element with `document.createElement` but you never use the _actual_ element, only the clones (:. This means you're creating 1 more element than I do.

Answer (score 4):

It comes down to the structure of the page. An HTML page is represented by the [Document Object Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). This is a [Tree Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure).

In a tree structure a node can have children. Allowing a node to be in two places at once would change the DOM from a Tree into a [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). If one node was an ancestor of another node that appeared as a child of itself, that would make it a graph with cycles (i.e. loops).

This doesn't match the structure of HTML.

If you want something to appear twice in the document, it has to appear twice in the Document Object Model. Even if two objects appear to be the same object twice, they're really two different but identical objects.

Answer (score 3):

The instance of the `buttonElement` only exists once, you'll have to recreate it again (or clone the initial one, as @Brian suggested) for it to be placed multiple times. Fortunately, you already *loop through* your nodelist, so you utilize this to create a new button per instance:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.Tabelle-Titel-nur-oben');

for(var i = 0; i< elements.length; i++) {
    var buttonElement = document.createElement("Button");
    var t0 = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
    buttonElement.appendChild(t0);
    document.body.insertBefore(buttonElement, elements[i]);
}
```