# Should I enhance Jquery Mobile elements on the client or send enhanced markup with data-enhance="false"?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-mobile

I have a product search where I'm sending back results with each result containing a two button JQM controlgroup.

I'm sending 24 records at a time, so this will be 24 controlgroups to enhance, like so:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="submitButton linkBox">
    <input type="button" class="singleLoader" data-brand="#d#" data-index="#e#" value="#tx#" />
    <input type="button" class="selector" data-brand="#d#" data-index="#e#" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="fav" value="#tx#" />
</div>
```

If I send the controlgroups as plain HTML and enhance them on the client, server response is `1sec`, data send `20k`, and the page noticably stalls for about another 1-2 seconds, presumable because JQM is busy enhancing the controlgroups.

I'm now trying the alternative, which is

```
  $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
```

and sending the fully enhanced markup instead of the controlgroup. So now I'm sending this:

```
<div data-enhance="false" class="ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal">
     <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls">
           <div data-icon="" data-iconpos="" class="ui-btn ui-corner-left ui-btn-up-c" aria-disabled="false">
                <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-left">
                     <span class="ui-btn-text">#tx#</span>
                </span>
                <input type="button" value="#tx#" class="ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false">
      </div>
      <div data-icon="fav" data-iconpos="notext" title="#tx#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-right ui-controlgroup-last ui-btn-up-c" aria-disabled="false">
           <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-right ui-controlgroup-last">
                <span class="ui-btn-text">#tx#</span>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-fav ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
           </span>
           <input type="button" value="#tx#" data-icon="fav" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false">
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

which increase transfered size to `34k` and response time to `1.5sec`, but the page feels noticabley faster, because there is nothing to enhance. However I also read that using `data-enhance=false`, this is a performance hit on devices.

**Question:**
Does anyone else have experience on how to handle this? Should I opt for large file size/transfer time/performance hit, if the page feels faster?

Comment: I've played a bit with this and I like loading already enhanced code into the DOM so there's no hanging where it feels like your website is broken. My main issue with this was that upgrading jQuery Mobile will be much more difficult if you have to change the output manually every-time. I even thought about creating a PHP plugin that automatically enhances the HTML server-side but again, that plugin would have to be maintained. Also, if you use a server-side script to compress the output I'm sure you can turn that `34k` into something more like `5k`.

Comment: agree on the hanging part, this is really annoying. I'm having to use Coldfusion on the server-side and 34k already compressed. A non-enhanced 2 button controlgroup is 477bytes, fully enhanced and striped from all data-attributes is 1.2k. Times 24 plus some text and image links. I wish it was closer to 5k, but I'm getting result with one "spinnerloop", so that's ok for now. Thanks for commenting. Make it answer?

Comment: @Jasper: what do you think about NOT calling `trigger("enhance")` on content AJAXed in, if it already is marked up? This way it should be possible to omit the `data-enhance="false"` on all controlgroups and also avoid the performance hit of searching for `data-enhance`. If it's just content I'm adding to a page that should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Jasper: have you ever tried gzipping Ajax responses? I'm still having a few errors but I managed to compress to gzip, send as gzip and have my enhanced HTML in Firebug (...not on screen yet). If I get it to work it would be <2k, <2sec and hopefully fully renedered. Fiddling some more with this.

Comment: last comment here... gzipping Ajax works. Down to a `1k` response, fully enhanced, no stalling. Pretty much perfect except for me still missing German characters äöü...

Comment: Pretty much any plain-text file-type will compress well. So if your response includes HTML, yeah, it'll gzip just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Basically there are three options. I ran every one with Firebug to check for files size/loading time and visual stall due to rendering items.

**a) As is**
I'm loading a listview with each of my 24 search results being list items, each with a two button controlgroup.

```
1 listview
24 list items
24 two button controlgroups
```

Skimming the markup to the essential stuff, I'm receiving `20k`, about `1sec` to send the results, but then the page visually stalls for about another 1-2 seconds before all items have been created.

**b) data-enhance=false**
This requires also setting `$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled=true` as JQM says scanning for `data-enhanced` is a performance hit (see [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/data-attributes.html)). I couldn't really notice though.

Doing this means you have to enhance anything you need yourself (in my case server-side), so I'm sending fully enhanced markup (Note: you could also try and remove data-attributes as they seem to only indicate to JQM, what classes to assign etc.)

Now my search returned `35k` in `1.5sec`, but the page rendering was much faster so this feels much better.

**c) don't enhance**
I was still using `trigger('create')` on stuff I was sending. However if I don't need to fire `create` on elements to enhance them since I already enhanced server-side, I don't need `data-enhance=false` and the global config which would also save the implied performance hit.

Turns out this also Works well. File size is still the same and I believe it goes even quicker (wish this would be measureable)...

So for now I'm perferring to send more data (`40k` including the pagination and enhanced listview/listitems) and it seems to be much more responsive.

Still curious what experiences others have, so please post what you find.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand JQM's progressive enhancement correctly the aim is to being able to adapt to the served platform on client side using this client-side approach (graceful degradation: [jQuery and dynamic elements vs display css attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333950/jquery-and-dynamic-elements-vs-display-css-attribute/11334556#11334556)). If you render everything on server-side you either need to serve the enhanced markup for different platforms or you'll only be able to support one platform: The one you copied the enhanced mark up from.

If latter is your requirement, e.g. to only support Android Chrome browser from version XY, this is fine to gain performance, if not it might become tedious.

I'm currently facing the same performance issue due to the enhancement of up to 60 form elements which takes 1s on Desktop but 6s on a Nexus 4 which is unbearable. These are my thoughts which I want to share before trying out to serve enhanced markup. We need to also support Windows Mobile 8 and iOS7 platform which why I'm hesitating.

Comment: The question is a little outdated. The advantage of JQM is that the source code you generate on the server works everywhere, so you only need to make it once. Some JQM widgets can be pre-enhanced, so you can generate the "finished" markup on the server and JQM will only create the underlying objects on the client = no heavy DOM manip = fast. If you don't want to pre-enhance on the server, do it on the client, but this means you will have to write your own enhancer, which can be difficult depending on your setting. I'm writing one currently but is not finished

Comment: the trick to your own enhancer must be that (1) you don't make HTML, (2) put it in the DOM and (3) ask JQM to `enhanceWithin`. Rather (1) assemble and (2) enhance in memory (documentFragment is your friend).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I got it, pre-enhancing does not break cross-browser-compatibility. I'm interested in the server-side part. Do you have a best practice at hand of creating pre-enhanced code? Or a Java library which I've overseen. Or is it simply copy&pasting the results from the browser?

Comment: I don't really have a server-side lib. Copy & paste would be a good start I guess.