# how to increase performance of jquery mobile for large number of data

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile with large amount of data. I am loading data using ajax the problem is after loading all data approx 600 records when I scroll up and click on search box(input type text) in header it takes too large time to respond.
Please help me to fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to approach this problem would be to try loading less data into the DOM at a time. Render fewer records (say 50) at a time, and add paging (or prev/next, more, etc.)

In jQuery Mobile, you could accomplish this by adding some buttons or links to the page that say prev/next etc., and in the event handler for the buttons, you can update your listview with a new set of records. You will have to call .listview('refresh') to restore the full styling and behavior to the listview.

I know it might not be ideal to only display a portion of your records, but considering the limited hardware performance of mobile devices, it might be necessary in order to get acceptable performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205787/should-i-enhance-jquery-mobile-elements-on-the-client-or-send-enhanced-markup-wi)

1. `send` your records as `enhanced markup` = do what Jquery Mobile would do with your 500 records server-side (this will increase the amount of data you transfer!)
2. use `data-enhance=false` (plus config) OR `don't listview("refresh")` to stop JQM from enhancing your already enhanced code
3. manually `gzip your ajax` response server-side to reduce the filesize again

This way you prevent JQM from enhancing 500 list items and keep the filesize transferred to a minimum

Comment: This approach is to reducing the data in API. but JQM apps still slow in navigation when loaded some data.